# Is there a way to pull all exchange events for a specific room using graphAPI

Tags: events, calendar, exchangewebservices, azure-ad-graph-api, outlook-restapi

Reviewing this, but not clear.  Not looking to do this for just my user and can run with elevated application rights with access to all calendars.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/calendar_list_events

Answer (score 0):

Yes you just need to make sure you give your application the following permission

> Calendars.Read.Shared Read user and shared calendars  Allows the app to read events in all calendars that the user can access, including delegate and shared calendars.

ref https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/permissions_reference

So as long as the calling account then has access to the Room Mailbox (eg via Delegation so they can access the same thing in Outlook etc) you just use the following endpoint

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('room@domain.com')/calendar/events
```